# "Join" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm searching on Internet the similar word of "join" in a sense to join a group, for example if I see some people talking together how is the better way I can say

> "Can I join the conversation"

in German?

I've already found some [results](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-german/join), but this doesn't help me so much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translation of *join* is rather context-dependent, and I agree that a dictionary might not provide the full details required for every situation.

Regarding the concrete example you cited,

> Can I join the conversation?

the translation would be

> Darf ich (auch) mitreden?
>   Darf ich mich einmischen?

There are also some variants like

> Stört es dich/Sie, wenn ich mich einmische? (*lit.* "Do you mind if I barge in?", or more loosely "May I weigh in?" or "May I interrupt?")

*sich einmischen* literally means *to barge in* or *to interfere*, and is used in a somewhat self-deprecating manner here to make the question more polite.

If you have other concrete examples on your mind, feel free to edit your question and we can help out.

Comment: btw he can also ask questions like this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language)

Answer (score 6):

I'll go for a more general answer. If you want to join ongoing activities the most common way would be to "mitverben"

> Kann ich mitspielen/singen/reden/machen.

If you want to join "officially" constituted social bodies like a club or something you'd use *beitreten* or *eintreten* or Mitglied werden bei*

> Ich bin ein einen Golfclub eingetreten / einem Golfclub beigetreten /bei einem Golfclub Mitglied geworden.

If you are joining groups that are groups solely because of characteristics they share, then you'd use "jetzt/auch dazu gehören"

> Ich gehöre jetzt auch zum Club der 30er.
>
> Ich gehöre jetzt auch zu den Hartzern.